# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet loginDispacher threw exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have made a simple program but getting following error. I am using Eclipse Kelper and Tomcat 7.0. Tried a lot of things, but nothing is working for me :(

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet loginDispacher threw
>   exception
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet loginDispacher threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   loginDispacher threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Class;
>     org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:260)
>     org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:83)
>     org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:63)
>     org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:54)
>     org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.(DefaultConversionService.java:43)
>     org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
>     org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
>     org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.(AbstractEnvironment.java:98)
>     org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
>     org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

The source code is very simple.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loginDispacher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginDispacher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**loginDispacher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sandeep.controller" />

    <!-- View resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.sandeep.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("From controller");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hellow Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sandeep</groupId>
  <artifactId>logindemo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>logindemo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>logindemo</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It seems you are having version mismatch error (NoSuchMethodError). Make sure all jars you have are compatible versions.

Comment: post the list of jars you have in your classpath.

Comment: Not very sure that it is version issue. I tried same on another system and it is working. This is wired!!

Comment: @M4ver1k: Added list of JARs (pom.xml)

Comment: since you are using maven can you try deleting org.springframework folder in side you .m2 folder and retry ?

Comment: @M4ver1k: Can you please advise the reason reason for same? By mistake I deleted .m2 folder and need to restore everything, which infect is going on till now :(

Comment: Well I have faced similar issues when using maven (not sure why this happen,my guess isthat while jars are pulled over network some data gets corrupted) and when I delete these jar(s) and do a clean install things work.

Comment: I having save error while run this code ,
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example

Comment: I faced the same error which got resolved once I changed my Spring jars version from 3.2 to 4.3.

Answer (score 5):

Try to change your spring framework version in pom.xml to 4.1.5 Just add this before your dependencies

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: yh this is the answer. i think this error occure becase of not compatible of psring version and  java version

Comment: This is the right answer! In the spring framework wiki page tells about [JDK version rage](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range) and also says that 3.2.x is EOL (reached its end of life) as of December 31st, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your web.xml

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/loginDispacher-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

And this ligne code in your loginDispacher-servlet.

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

In the following share examples with spring mvc : [link](https://drive.google.com/a/tritux.com/?tab=mo#folders/0B8Ik6XpzSgXTdlhtVnR6LUdoRzg)

Comment: Since he is following dispatcherservletname-servlet.xml naming convention no need to explicitly specify the name .Also above mentioned will only work if u register a ContextLoaderListener.
As he have <context:component-scan base-package="com.sandeep.controller" /> in spring xml no need to specify <context:annotation-config />

Answer (score 0):

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Both web.xml and applicationContext.xml xsd should be the same. Please change once.

Answer (score 0):

For the component scan tag component:scan the base package attribute value should be "com.sandeep". You are mentioning one level inside to scan.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.