# Why i cannot access to services CXF in tomcat : HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: spring, maven, web-services, tomcat, cxf

When i run it on tomcat server it returns the following error in services page i cant  access to  WSDL and SOAP

I have this error :

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> "Servlet.init ()" message for servlet [CXFServlet] raised an exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from satisfying the request.
>
> exception javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init ()" for
>   servlet [CXFServlet] raised an exception
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Content of files :

cxf-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

  <jaxws:server id="hallo" address="/hallo">
  <jaxws:serviceBean>
   <bean class="CXF-Maven.DemoClass"/>
  </jaxws:serviceBean>
  </jaxws:server>

</beans>
```

`http://localhost:8080/`  working fine 
but  `http://localhost:8080/CXF-Maven/services` I can not pass it

Comment: Did you post the full stack trace that the server is returning? I think there should be some nested exception below the one you pasted which will lead you (and us) to the reason why the CXF servlet is crashing.

Comment: I'm new in JavaEE and i can't understanding what exactly means by returning ?  Is there a bug in my file ?

Comment: After the line `java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)` there usually comes line `root cause` followed by another exception. Check sample stack posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851236/spring-mvc-http-status-500-servlet-init-for-servlet-logindispacher-threw-e/29251750 Unless in your case it is all the server returns/logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem at a vesion when i am  using the old version of dependencies on file `pom.xml`
updated the file configuration `pom.xml` to the new version everthing works well  now. thnaks

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demowb</groupId>
  <artifactId>demowb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>cxfweb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>demoweb</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```